# c++ ODBC Connection string

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

In VC++, I used ODBC to connect Database with the following string:

```
SQLDriverConnect (sqlconnectionhandle, 
             NULL, 
             L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=serverIP, 1433;Database=DBName;Uid=aaa;Pwd=bbb;",
             SQL_NTS, 
             retconstring, 
             1024, 
             NULL,
             SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
```

my question is how to input the userName and userPw generically withou hardcoding.

Here, L means Unicode.

eg: (this example doesnt work)

```
SQLWCHAR userName = L"aaa";
SQLWCHAR userPw = L"bbb";
SQLWCHAR connString = L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=serverIP, 1433;Database=DBName;Uid=" + userName + ";Pwd=" + userPw + ";",
```

Here is an example for concat strings:(works!)

```
wchar_t* subString = L" currentDate = '2013-01-04' ";

SQLWCHAR queryString[] = L"select * from Table1 WHERE ";
wcscat_s(queryString, subString );
```

Comment: This will definitely help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L"stringName" means this is Unicode string, using SQLDriverConnectA can solve the problem.

eg:

```
SQLDriverConnectA(sqlconnectionhandle, 
         NULL, 
         "Driver={SQL Server};Server=serverIP, 1433;Database=DBName;Uid=aaa;Pwd=bbb;",
         SQL_NTS, 
         retconstring, 
         1024, 
         NULL,
         SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used SQLBindParameter to bind SQLStatement and SQLExecDirect to execute the statment.

```
eg: SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, queryString, SQL_NTS)
```